# Why mysqldump exchange lat long coordinates in geometry fields (multipolygon) after dump?

Tags: mysql, geometry, polygon, mysql-8.0

First of all, thank you for taking the time to read this.
I have a issue. With this database i am able to create a dump with the following command line (bash linux):

```
mysqldump -u root -h localhost --hex-blob -p 'databasepassword' content > "dumps/content.sql"
```

[image: Geometry content on original database]

With this dump file i am able to restore my database with the following command line (linux bash):

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p content < content.sql
```

But, afterwords, my lat and long coordinates are exchanged.

[image: Exchanged lat long coordinates]

Original database mysql version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Dump restore mysql version: mysql  Ver 8.0.30 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

I would like to be able to restore a sql dump without corrupt my geometry data.

Comment: _For reference_ You are moving data from mariaDB to MySQL. They were the same, but they are no longer that similiar.

Comment: If i install the same mariaDB version on my local machine maybe i have this issue fixed?